# gsed macOSX in-place string replacement line by line

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to use the `gsed` command to replace strings line by line in my file by passing in the string as the parameter. Here is an example of what I have:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  if [[ $line != *'{'* ]] && [[ $line == *"property"* ]]; then
    $line | gsed -r '/name="property"/{s@(.*value=")([^"]*)(".*)@\1$R{\2.LABEL}\3@g;}'
   property_value=$(grep -oE '{[^/]+}' | cut -c2- | rev | cut -c2- | rev)
  fi
done < "$file2"
```

The issue here is that I'm trying to loop over my file line by line using `IFS` and the `read` command while also executing `gsed` inside of the `while loop`.

The problem with this, is that `gsed` tends to read the entire file if you pass in the filename, but I only want to use `gsed` to do an in-place replacement on the string that I pass into it.

The reason I need to do this line by line is because I need to save the `$property_value` variable which I will later be appending to another file if it meets the `if` condition inside the `while` loop.

To summarize, I want to format a string inside of my file if it meets the `if` condition statement, save the `property value` in this string to a variable and append it to another file. Maybe the way I'm approaching this isn't the best but if there is some sort of other technique of doing this I'm open to suggestions.

As an example here is some example input:

```
<property name="property" value="EXAMPLE"/>
```

After running the gsed command I want to perform an inplace string replacement in my file that matches this a property in this format:

```
<property name="property" value="$R{EXAMPLE.LABEL}"/>
```

And finally I using the grep command, I want to extract the `EXAMPLE.LABEL` value to a variable which I will eventually append to another file

Comment: It would be helpful to provide sample input and your desired output.

Comment: @glennjackman I've updated the question with an example, hopefully this clarifies things a bit more

Comment: For XML data, you should be using an XML parser, like [tag:xmlstarlet] or [tag:xmllint]

Comment: @glennjackman Sounds good I'll look into this some more! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
 $line | gsed -r '/name="property"/{s@(.*value=")([^"]*)(".*)@\1$R{\2.LABEL}\3@g;}'
```

try

```
line=$(gsed -r '/name="property"/{s@(.*value=")([^"]*)(".*)@\1$R{\2.LABEL}\3@g;}' <<<"$line")
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for the gsed command, but I'm also having trouble saving the grep portion to a variable, any idea on how I save that to a variable?

Comment: You want that grep acting on ... what? 
The modified $line variable?

Comment: Yeah the modified line variable. So pretty much an example of what I'm formatting is this:
<property name="property" value="EXAMPLE"/>
Which turns into this after formatting:
<property name="property" value="$R{EXAMPLE.LABEL}"/>
and I want to extract the string "EXAMPLE" using grep

Comment: You're not providing any input to grep, so it's slurping up the rest of the file. Do `grep -option '...' <<<"$line" | cut ...` like I did for the gsed command.

Comment: This solved it, thanks!
Updated it to 
`line=$(grep -oE '{[^/]+}' <<<"$line" | cut -c2- | rev | cut -c2- | rev)`